# .ISO on Windows file server is locked and cannot be deleted (Folder Redirection GPO)

Tags: group-policy

I am testing out a Folder Redirection GPO for our domain (DC is Server 2008) and have run into an issue. I placed a 2.6 GB .ISO file on my "network" desktop (on the file server) as a test and opened it on a workstation, but I do not remember which workstation. Now I cannot delete the ISO. I have rebooted all workstations, but for some reason Windows still sees the ISO as in use and I get the error:

*File in use. The action can't be completed because the file is open in another program. Close the file and try again.*

Before anyone berates me for not putting this question on SuperUser, please understand that I felt the GPO for Folder Redirection qualified this as a SF question. Thank you.

Comment: Check for a lock file in everyone's redirected folder. If you find one and you can delete it then that may do the trick. If not, then log onto each workstation and see if one of them has the ISO mounted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **Manage Session** from the File server to see who locked the file. (I used 2008R2 printscreen as I don't know what OS you use, but it's only to show you what you can see from that menu)

From there;

[image]

A screen like that should display with the open file session;

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks very much, @yagmoth555. :)

Answer (score 2):

Run [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) on the server.  Use the 'Find -> Find Handle' menu option, and provide the filename of the ISO.  You should see what process has the file open, and be able to terminate, or restart that process/service.

Comment: I'm sure this would've worked too, but I didn't have Process Explorer handy so I just used the built-in tools in Server Mgr. Thank you all the same though!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the same task by opening Windows Command Processor.
Open Run - type "cmd" (without quotes) - openfiles - Enter.

www.ghacks.net/2011/07/04/openfiles-display-files-opened-by-network-users/